# Nodejs can't find includes when running from relative path

Tags: node.js, directory

I have nodejs code in **the_second_folder** but I want to run it from the root folder. When I run the code **from the_second_folder** I get no errors, but when I run the code from the root folder nodejs crashes because of includes. Here is the code:

```
require('rootpath')(); //does not work

var file_to_include = "file.js";
eval(fs.readFileSync(file_to_include)+'');
```

This only works when I run the code from **the_second_folder** (where it is) but fails when running from the root folder (-1 in the folder tree). 
The error is precisely about the inclusion of file_to_include

**What I'd like to know is how can I run the node script in a relative folder scope even when called from root folder.**

**EDIT**

```
file_to_include ABSOLUTE_PATH
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'file_to_include.js'
...
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/the_second_folder/socket.io/lib/client.js:3:9)
...
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/the_second_folder/socket.io/lib/index.js:12:14)
```

Now the error happens in socket.io... any idea on this?

Comment: Because of relative paths.

Comment: @Scimonster I know x) how can I do it so everything is relative then when called from other folder?

Comment: But you're not asking how to fix it, you're asking why it happens, and it sounds like that's not what you really want to know. I recommend you [edit] to ask what you intend. If it's clear after that, i'll undownvote.

Comment: @Scimonster done, would you mind helping me now please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the global [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname), which returns the directory of the current script.

You can then do something like:

```
var file_to_include = "file.js";
eval(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,file_to_include))+'');
```

But may i ask why you are `eval()`ing a JS file instead of just `require()`ing it?

Comment: Why wouldn't I? I'm in development stage. This solution is not working. It does find the file but the error happens in the socket.io module... I'll update the question and let you know

Comment: please do check the question now :)